# Deleting dynamically created checkboxes in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am a novice in Python and wxpython. I tried to write a code ,in which I have to create Checkboxes based on the user input of a Combobox. I am able to do it. But when I am changing the selections , the old Checkboxes are still there and I am unable to find a way to destroy them or refresh. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Here is my code :

```
import wx
class Form1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        wx.EVT_COMBOBOX(self, 30, self.EvtComboBox)
        self.lblhear = wx.StaticText(self,-1,"APPLICATION",wx.Point(30, 295))
        self.lblhear3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "TASKS TO BE DONE", wx.Point(30, 370))
        self.sampleList = ['ABC', 'PQR']
        self.edithear=wx.ComboBox(self, 30, "",
            wx.Point(110, 290), wx.Size(95, -1),
            self.sampleList, wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.AppSelect, self.edithear)
    def AppSelect(self, event):
        if event.GetString() == "ABC":
            self.Application = 'ABC'
            self.cb_list = []
            act_list = ['Task1','Task2']
        elif event.GetString() == "PQR":
            self.Application = 'PQR'
            self.cb_list = []
            act_list = ['Task3','Task4']
        pos_y = 380
        id_cb = 100
        for i in act_list:
            pos_y += 20
            id_cb += 20
            self.cb = wx.CheckBox(self, id_cb, label=i, pos=(50, pos_y))
            self.cb.SetValue(False)
            self.cb_list.append(self.cb)
    def EvtComboBox(self, event):
        if event.GetId() == 30:
            self.Application = self.event.GetString()
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(1200,800))
Form1(frame)
frame.Show(1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I suspect your code does not reach the place where you create the CheckBoxes. Try watching the program output and removing the errors one by one. Then we can proceed. Also, you have a better chance of being answered if you post a minimal example of your code.

Comment: Hi Petr, Thanks for looking into the code. But I am not sure, what you meant by 'not reaching the place where you create the CB'. I am able to create the CB but only unable to delete or destroy the old ones. I have edited the script as you suggested.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? You might forget to redraw the frame after checkbox deletion

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thanks. I have added the Miinimal,Complete & Verifiable example now.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy the existing checkbox widgets by calling their `Destroy` method. Perhaps something like this:

```
for cb in self.cb_list:
    cb.Destroy()
```

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks a lot for taking a look into my code. I have tried your suggestion earlier but to no avail. The problem is when I move my cursor over CheckBoxes, the old value is getting visible.

Comment: Surjith, if I add exactly these lines at the top of you AppSelect, and also self.cb_list = [] somewhere into the costructor, it works.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if I may suggest, look into sizers in future. Absolute positioning of the widgets works, but when you come across different DPI or font size settings, things may start looking weird. For example in my setup, I see only APPLICATIO, the N gets covered by the combo box.

Comment: @Petr Blahos, Thank you very much. If I put it as you suggested, it works. I will add the sizers in my new codes, as it makes more sense.

Comment: @RobinDunn I reserve my gratitude for your help. Your response wasnt even in my wild dreams.

Comment: @PetrBlahos May I know, if there is any way to switch back to the Application ABC and get the tasks assigned to that ? Because when I try that, it gives me the following error.
raise PyDeadObjectError(self.attrStr % self._name)
wx._core.PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of the CheckBox object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed.